# attempting to add cost from the end of a line but only getting a blank space

Tags: python, slice

I'm attempting to get the cost (the values at the end of each line) total from all the logs but when price is printed it doesn't print anything just a blank space. Each line has varying length before the value. This code does not yet add the cost but I'm making sure I'm getting.

log record entered into function (rec.dat): *this log would be the record entered into the function

@ 2014 2 14 00:03:01 Matt "login" 0.01

@ 2014 2 14 02:06:12 Mary "login" 0.01

@ 2014 2 14 17:12:05 Mary "cd ~/cs150/projects" 0.01

function:
the goal of the function is to add how much the cost would be for all actions (in this case cost should end up totaling .03)

```
def cost(rec):
    s = Scanner(rec)
    cost = 0
    line = s.readline()
    for i in range(0, len(rec), 1):
        info = len(line) - 3
        price = line[info:0]
        print("price: ",price)
        cost += price
        line = s.readline()
    s.close()
    return cost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that:

```
price = line[-3:]
```

You can delete `info` completely. Look up how Python's [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) works, it provides handy shortcuts for a large number of problems, including yours :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me 'price = line[info:0] needs to be 'price = line[info:]'

```
>>> a = 'abcde'
>>> a[2:]
'cde'
>>> a[2:0]
''
>>>
```